# Can we decrypt a cipher text encrypted using different algorithm?

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, aes

Can we decrypt a cipher text encrypted using different algorithm?

For example, I have cipher text that is encrypted using DES encryption algorithm but I have securekey to decrypt the cipher text. So, my question is, Is it possible to decrypt using AES algorithm( different from encryption algorithm ) with the secure key generated using DES algorithm?

Comment: sure. will it be readable, though? Highly doubt it.

Comment: It depends what you mean by *impossible*. At the laymen level, yes, it's impossible. But at the expert level cryptographers mostly deal in probabilities. Suppose your plaintext is 16 bytes, then the probability that a given random AES key will AES-decrypt your ciphertext into your plaintext is about 2\**(-128). Thus, mathematically, we cannot say it is impossible. So your question lacks the specificity needed to answer exactly, and also it's not really on-topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Once the key material size is the same, of course you could execute any cipher against any cipher text (notwithstanding padding/block size compatibility), that said you will not receive anything close to the original plaintext.

In fact you will get absolute nonsense out.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.